# MYSQL error message- Changing the INTERVAL to 24hrs (from 23hrs) causes ERROR 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change the interval from 23hrs to 24hrs in the following snippet of script:

```
BETWEEN (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 23 HOUR)
```

When I do that I get the error message referenced above (see subject line). I just cant understand why other than it has something to do with crossing over into a new day (that is my hunch anyway). If I leave the hours as 23 my query (added below) return 26 rows. If I change it to 24hrs or more I get the error. I would appreciate any help or advice as I would really like to understand the error of my was and then fix it.

```
SELECT 
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS SHIFTDATE,
t1.start_date_time, t1.end_date_time,
CASE
WHEN t1.start_date_time >= (SELECT cast(concat(start_date, ' ', (SEC_TO_TIME(start_time*60))) as datetime) FROM `austcor_map`.`DWNTIM` 
WHERE shift_id_number = 2 AND machine_number = 35 AND start_date BETWEEN (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
AND t1.end_date_time <= (SELECT cast(concat(finish_date, ' ', (SEC_TO_TIME(finish_time*60))) as datetime) 
FROM `austcor_map`.`DWNTIM` 
WHERE shift_id_number = 2 AND machine_number = 35 AND finish_date BETWEEN (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 23 HOUR))  
THEN 'DAY'
END AS Shift
FROM `austcor_map`.`PDETLH` t1
WHERE t1.start_date_time >= (SELECT cast(concat(start_date, ' ', (SEC_TO_TIME(start_time*60))) as datetime) FROM `austcor_map`.`DWNTIM` 
WHERE shift_id_number = 2 AND machine_number = 35 AND start_date BETWEEN (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 23 HOUR))
AND t1.end_date_time <= (SELECT cast(concat(finish_date, ' ', (SEC_TO_TIME(finish_time*60))) as datetime) FROM `austcor_map`.`DWNTIM` 
WHERE shift_id_number IN (2) AND machine_number = 35 AND finish_date BETWEEN (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 23 HOUR))
AND t1.corrugator_number = 1 GROUP BY PROGRAM WITH ROLLUP
```

Note where I use SEC_TO_TIME there should be an asterix before 60 but it is being striped out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't have more than one value in your `between` condition. So the query `DATE_ADD((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))` must produce only one result

Comment: Hey Jeurgen, hank you for your reply. So if I understand you, when I cross over into a new day the query would return two separate dates i.e. 28th and 29th for example- and that is the multiple rows. Where when the query was set to 23 hours it returned only one date i.e. 28th?

Comment: Another thing `CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY` returns `2021-09-28` while `DATE_ADD((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 23 HOUR)` returns `2021-09-28 23:00:00` maybe you should have time on both ?

Comment: Solved!! Hoorayyyyy. Here is the updated code:

Comment: (SELECT 
cast(concat(start_date, ' ', (SEC_TO_TIME(start_time*60))) as datetime) 
FROM `austcor_map`.`DWNTIM` 
WHERE 
shift_id_number = 2 AND machine_number = 35 AND start_date IN (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND  (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR))